# Fetching Data from firebase using Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get data from my Firebase database here is my code.

```
   FirebaseUser current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   String uid = current_user.getUid();

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"UId "+uid,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   /*ref_getvalue=*/FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ChildParentNumberForLogin").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           childname= dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
           childParentNumber= dataSnapshot.child("Parent Number").getValue().toString();
       }


       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

           Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Error in reading in data "+databaseError.getCode(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }
   });
```

**AND my database**

[image]

I want to fetch that value but I always get null value

Comment: dont add space change Parent Number to ParentNumber

Comment: i didnot get your point.. where i have not add spaces..???

Comment: Check you security rules. Make sure they allow reading

Comment: @Peter & Rosario: the space appears both in the JSON and the code, so what problem do you see with it?

Comment: @AbuBakar What's the problem with this code? You're not doing anything with `childname` and `childParentNumber`, so its hard to say what the intended result is.

Comment: Was just guessing that the problem, maybe from the space since the code seems okay. But did not say anything after that..(as I do not think its the problem, its because of something else)

Comment: The Realtime database does support having keys with spaces (if that's what you think the problem is) @PeterHaddad

Comment: @AbuBakar Your code looks correct. Have you tried to log the `childname` and `childParentNumber`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the post id very easy, and do not have to save it in the database.
Try something like this:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     childname= dataSnapshot.child(datasnapshot.getKey()).child("Name").getValue().toString();
     childParentNumber= dataSnapshot.child(datasnapshot.getKey())child("Parent Number").getValue().toString();
 }
```

`datasnapshot.getKey()` gets the parent wich is ( for Example ): "krgPivI6nsYbfjzclho7eYH6Ftp2"

Comment: what is the child uid in his code? child("ChildParentNumberForLogin").child(uid)

Comment: Actually uid is userID. em getting this cause i'm storing data under this id.
when a user registered in my app firebase give user unique id as em registering user with email.

Comment: @Karl Wolf em getting error.... datasnapshot.getParent() while doing this..

Comment: @AbuBakar Try datasnapshot.getKey()